# About a corollary of Krull theorem for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

A corollary of [Krull's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_theorem) says that in a commutative ring $R$ every non-unit lie in a maximal ideal of $R$. Well, my question is if this works for noncommutative rings.

So far, I got this: every non-left (right) invertible element of an arbitrary ring $R$ lie in a maximal left (right) ideal of $R$. Is this correct? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which theorem? One usually sees this as a simple application of the axiom of choice, so I wonder if it is the same proof.

Comment: I assume it is this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_theorem

Comment: @arkeet OK, probably so, and that's the same thing. I always thought of it as folklore but it sounds like this is attributable :)

Comment: I'm reading books where rings must have an identity, sorry for not pointing out. Also, in these books the result I was asking for help it's set as a corollary for Krull theorem for commutative rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. If $R$ is any ring with $1$ and $x \in R$ is not left-invertible, then $1 \notin Rx$, and therefore $Rx$ must be contained in a maximal left ideal. (You prove this in the same way as for commutative rings: The collection of left ideals containing $Rx$ but not $1$ is nonempty, so Zorn's lemma applies to show that it has a maximal element, which must be a maximal left ideal.)

Comment: @rschwieb Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: Definitely better, but the pitfall of someone thinking that Zorn's lemma applies to the set of proper ideals in rings (possibly without identity) is still there. That's why I was emphasizing the criterion of not containing $1$ over "proper".

Comment: @rschwieb Perhaps I have fallen in the pit, but why might Zorn's lemma not apply?

Comment: There exist rings without identity such that the poset of proper ideals does not have maximal elements.  You can try it: there isn't any way to prove that a union of a chain of proper ideals is proper (in general.) If an identity exists and you use "not containing $1$" as a replacement for proper, then everything goes through: a union of a chain of ideals not containing $1$ is indeed an ideal not containing $1$.

Comment: @rschwieb Alright, then it should be clarified that the ring must be unital.

Comment: @rschwieb I guess as a counterexample when $R$ is not unital: If $R$ is the nonunital ring of integer sequences with finitely many nonzero elements (with operations pointwise), then $\{\mathbb{Z}^n\}$ is a chain of proper ideals whose union is all of $R$.

Comment: Yes, the union of initial segments of $\mathbb Z ^\omega$ is a good example.